# Удаленная работа с БД на C#

Tags: c#, wpf, алгоритм

Прошу подсказать с архитектурой, завтра на работе предстоит делать большой проект.

Суть:

- Пользователь заходит на сайт, делает что-то и в базу пишется то что он хочет
- Программа сообщает нужному компьютеру что пришел новый клиент(обновляется раз в минуту на наличие новых клиентов) и показывается в трее, тут же запрос на распечатку
- Менеджер видит клиента и его заказ, распечатывает форму заказа с данными
- Выполняются действия, и заказ переводится в режим "Выполнен"

**Вообщем жесть!**

И так, подключаюсь я удаленно с mysql, беру таблицу например orders и вывожу ее, раз в минуту я ее обновляю, тут вопрос:

```
 Как правильно сообщать что новый клиент пришел?
```

Есть такая идея пока, менеджер же не будет смотреть все заказы, по этому можно сделать select where `orders` = 'Не выполнен' типа такого, записать кол-во rows которые вернула база, например 5, через минуту проверяю опять 5, опять проверяю уже 6 ( > 5), т.е. появился новый заказ, правильно ли я мыслю то, друзья?
Как перевести заказ в режим выполнено это я понимаю как буду делать.

**Чуть не забыл!Самый главный вопрос!**

Как правильно достать таблицу с удаленной базы и вывести ее на форме, а то вариант с качать всю базу каждую минуту не вариант...

Вообщем если еще есть идеи по архитектуре, подсказывайте.

---

Блин, я теперь не засну, думать буду...

Comment: Судя по вопросу вас интересует не архитектура, а собственно механизм как это делать. К тому же неясно - веб морда где вводятся заказы есть или нет? В общем вопрос переформулируйте пояснее

Comment: Учите, как работать с remote database в C#. Задача на самом деле очень простая, на средничка =)

Answer (score 2):

Я бы работал из WPF с БД через WCF сервисы, а именно dualBindings для двустороннего общения. Это позволит уйти от таймеров и спама бд постоянными запросами от клиентов (1-й вопрос). При добавлении нового клиента вытаскивайте новую информацию и засылайте ее клиентам, вызовом "колбека" (2-й).

Answer (score 0):

1. Пришел заказ
2. Менеджеру показывается уведомление (новых заказов 5).
3. Менеджер давит кнопку, ему выдается первый заказ по порядку, и одновременно переводится статус у этого заказа на в обработке.
   3.1. второй менеджер давит кнопку и ему выдается заказ из оставшихся новых.
4. Менеджер звонит клиенту, согласовывает заказ. По окончании ставит статус к отправке.
5. Курьер везет заказ. Возвращается в офис, сдает бабло в кассу, ставит заказ выполнен.

как-то так.